# Hiding formula with two different values

Tags: hide

i have a hiding formula on the new entry form-- `=if([$StatusAnsuchen]=='Pending','false', 'true')` that works fine so far.

but now i´d like to add another statement based on other columns value--`=if([$Ansuchen]=='Andere','true', 'false')`

how can i add them together?
i tried ...`=if([$StatusAnsuchen]=='Pending','false', 'true' && [$Ansuchen]=='Andere','true', 'true'))`
but its not working...

thanks for any help

kurt

Comment: Why do you have different outputs at `=if([$Ansuchen]=='Andere','true', 'false')` & `[$Ansuchen]=='Andere','true', 'true'` in your question? I suppose this is by mistake, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below format to concatenate multiple conditions,

```
=if([$StatusAnsuchen]=='Pending' ,'false',if([$Ansuchen]=='Andere','true', 'false') )
```

The above formula runs on below condition,

- `IF StatusAnsuchen = Pending` Then Hides the column
- `If StatusAnsuchen != Pending  and Ansuchen != 'Andere'` Then Hides the column

Hope this helps you to apply the formula based on your needs.

Edited---
As per your below comments, try any of the below formulae,

```
=if([$StatusAnsuchen] !='Pending' ,if([$Ansuchen] != 'Andere','true', 'false'), 'false' )

=if([$StatusAnsuchen] != 'Pending' && [$Ansuchen] != 'Andere', 'true', 'false')
```

Comment: but If StatusAnsuchen != Pending  and Ansuchen != 'Andere' it should show the column...now it  hides it

Comment: Try any of the below formula,   =if([$StatusAnsuchen] != 'Pending' && [$Ansuchen] != 'Andere', 'true', 'false')      or     =if([$StatusAnsuchen] !='Pending' ,if([$Ansuchen] != 'Andere','true', 'false'), 'false' )

Comment: thank you very much. that did it...

Comment: Great. :)  If the response solves the problem! accept the response as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to perform **AND (&&)** operation between two conditions (correct me if I am wrong).

So, try using below:

```
=if([$StatusAnsuchen] == 'Pending' && [$Ansuchen] != 'Andere', 'false', 'true')
```

For more examples, you can refer official documentation: [Show or hide columns in a list or library form](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide)